# Is there any API REST OR SOAP API available to find the limit of user license available in the Marketing cloud org

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, ssjs, user-management

Is there any API REST OR SOAP API available to find the limit of user license in the Marketing cloud org .

Answer (score 3):

You won't find any information about the limits within Marketing Cloud. There is a number of metric subject to licensing (super messages, business units, contacts, api calls), but getting the actual status (consumption vs allowance) is not possible utilising any of the APIs, neither it is something which is visible in the user interface as well.